# setting 2 values for a field in a discord embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I need to make a discord embed with a field that has value= but I need two values to show up in the same field, I'm pulling data from an API and I have this code:

```
        itemobtain = item['obtained']['obtained']
        itemobtaintype = item['obtained']['type']
```

Obtained Obtained prints the cost of the item in the store and obtained type prints the currency used for that item, I need type to show up right after the cost but in the same field
For example if `itemobtain` was 800 and `itemobtaintype` was vbucks I need the field to say "800 vbucks"

I tried this code:

```
embed.add_field(name="Obtainable from", value='{}'.format(itemobtain), value='{}\n'.format(itemobtaintype), inline=False)
```

but got an error "keyword argument repeated" as I expect you can't have two value=. does anyone know how to do this or if its possible?

Answer (score 0):

after fiddling for a bit the correct code is

```
embed.add_field(name="Obtainable from", value='{} {{}}'.format(itemobtain).format(itemobtaintype), inline=True)
```

Comment: You could also do `value='{} {}'.format(itemobtain, itemobtaintype)`